# C# Fetching a specific value out of an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml

I am desperately trying to adapt an API from which I want to fetch a specific value out of an array and I can't seem capable of doing so.

Specifically, I am trying to fetch a custom field name and value out of the API where the name is Controller and the value is whatever the user gave it a value of (its a string value).

I order to get to this, I need to use what is called an IGame interface, which has several properties and methods within it. All of the properties are used with game proceeded with the name of the property. For example, `game.title` or `game.Platform`.

So, doing `this.Controller.Text = game.Title;` outputs the game title to the UI. So far, so good.

My problem comes when using the methods, whering the custom fields lie. I have to use `GetAllCustomFields` which has the syntax of `ICustomField[] GetAllCustomFields()`. The return value is `ICustomField[]` whose syntax in turn is `public interface ICustomField` with the properties of `GameId`, `Name`, `Value`.

Unfortunately, the API gives me no further information on actual usage so I'm left to try to figure it out but to no avail.

Here what i have so far:

```
    public void OnSelectionChanged(FilterType filterType, string filterValue, IPlatform platform, IPlatformCategory category, IPlaylist playlist, IGame game)
    {
        if (game == null)
        {
            this.Controller.Text = "HellO!";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string field in game.GetAllCustomFields(ICustomField[Name]))
            {
                this.Controller.Text = "The " + Name + " is " + Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Controller" />
</Grid>
```

Can someone help me restructure the `foreach` so it actually works?

Comment: It sounds like you want `foreach (ICustomField field in game.GetAllCustomFields())` in your for loop, and then `this.Controller.Text = "The " + field.Name + " is " + field.Value;`

Comment: I knew I was close! thank you!

Comment: One thing though, there can be several different custom fields so how do I ensure I'm only displaying the field with the name Controller? If users have mutiple different field names, I dont want to output everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var controllerFields = game.GetAllCustomFields().Where(f => f.Name == "Controller");

foreach (var field in controllerFields)
{
    this.Controller.Text = "The " + field.Name + " is " + field.Value;
}
```

Or if it is just one Controller-field:

```
Controller.Text = game.GetAllCustomFields()
                      .SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Controller")
                      ?.Value ?? "No controller here";
```

`?.Value` will return the value of the field if it was found. If not, that question mark will prevent to access `.Value` because it would lead to a NullReferenceException. By adding `?? "No controller here"`, you give a fallback which is returned if no Controller field was found. That opererator (`?.`) is called the [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#C.23), if you don't know it yet.